# Почему не работает выборка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, почему я немогу обратиться к `$('body')` через `scrollers.element`, получаю: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined` но вот так `$('body').mCustomScrollbar()` работает

```
    scrollers.element.mCustomScrollbar(); 

    var scrollers = [
        {
            element: $('body'),
            params:{
                scrollInertia:100,
                autoHideScrollbar: true
            },
            options:{
                type:'width',
                value: 1024
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `scrollers` — это массив, чтобы обратиться к `element` нужно записать так:
`scrollers[0].element.mCustomScrollbar();`

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка говорит вам, что невозможно прочитать свойство `element` у `undefined`. Это потому что значение `scrollers` присваивается после обращения к `scrollers.element`. @Maxim Zasorin также прав, `scrollers` — это массив, чтобы обратиться к первому элементу нужно использовать индекс 0 `scrollers[0]`.

```
var scrollers = [
    {
        element: $('body'),
        params:{
            scrollInertia:100,
            autoHideScrollbar: true
        },
        options:{
            type:'width',
            value: 1024
        }
    }
]
scrollers[0].element.mCustomScrollbar();
```